# Is it possible to execute tensorflow-on-spark program without gpu suppport?

Tags: python, apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark

I want tensor-flow-on-spark programs(for learning purpose),& I don't have a gpu support . Is it possible to execute tensor-flow on spark program without GPU support?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use CPU. Tensorflow will automatically use CPU if it doesn't find any GPU on your system.

Comment: thank you for the response. Can I execute gpu code in my system?

Comment: You will have to set tf.device() as CPU

Comment: let me check that, so If I change' device =cpu' instead of 'device=gpu',then that code will work, right?